# How to update the textview content display rapidly in android?

Tags: android, performance, user-interface, android-camera, textview

I want to update the textview showing the current photo number rapidly when long pressed the shutter button to activate the burst shot in Camera. As we know , we do the burst shot in Camera, the system is busy and maybe it will not refresh the textview immediately . So I have done some operations like this:

1. Using the runnable + handler:
2. post the runnable when the current photo number is updated
3. call the TextView.setText(number) in the run()

   ```
   private Runnable mShowBurstNumberRunnable = new Runnable() {

       public void run() {
           mBurstShotTextView.setText(mCurrentShotsNum);
       }
   }


   private PictureCallback mContinuousJpegPictureCallback = new PictureCallback() {
       public void onPictureTaken(final byte[]data, android.hardware.Camera camera) {
           ...
           mCurrentShotsNum++;
           mHandler.post(mShowBurstNumberRunnable);
           ...
       }
   }
   ```

But sometimes the textview can't display the number rapidly what I expected.
I am using Android 4.2.

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure that the mHandler which posting your mShowBurstNumberRunnable was attached on main thread. Only main thread could change the UI.

You also could try this

```
private PictureCallback mContinuousJpegPictureCallback = new PictureCallback() {
    public void onPictureTaken(final byte[]data, android.hardware.Camera camera) {
        ...
        mCurrentShotsNum++;
        mBurstShotTextView.post(mShowBurstNumberRunnable);
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: In fact, the code I pasted works well. Now, make sure the textview can be displayed in time is the main goal. I know the principle "Only main thread could change the UI" in android.

Comment: May be the code after mHandler.post(mShowBurstNumberRunnable)  execution time is too long. You could put them in back thread to run your task.